# Passing AJAX call from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 4 links on an html page [home page]. I would like each link to go to the same url [link page], but for the html on this link page to change depending on which link you pressed on the [home page]. I want to do this with an ajax call to [getData.php] but would love to hear other more elegant ideas if there are any.

I may be way off, but I imagine the click function on the [home page] will make an Ajax call that looks something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var href = this.href;  // get href from link
    e.preventDefault();  // don't follow the link
    $.post("getData.php", {
        //somehow indicate which link was clicked to send along with the ajax call
        }, function(){ 
              document.location = href;  // redirect browser to link
        }
    });
});
```

Then what does the php have to look like? It would probably have an If function that would echo 4 different things depending on what link was clicked. But then how does the [link page] get that html? Can the php just change the [link page's] html on its own or does the [link page] have to do something to receive the specific echo'd content?

Comment: Your ajax call should happen on the target page[link page]

Comment: What is the reason for this intercept? Process flow shown makes no sense. What problem does it try to solve?

Comment: @lshettyl But how would the [link page] know what link was clicked? I assumed they both need an ajax call. The [home page] ajax call would feed data to an IF variable on the php page which would determine what to echo, and then the [link page] would use an ajax call to retrieve that echo. I just need help writing the php code.

Comment: @charlietfl The best answer to your question is - because I want to learn how to do it. My example for this question is a simplified version of a process I would like to learn about. With 4 links it would be easy to just create 4 separate pages. But what if there are hundreds of links? Isn't the role of back end code to generate html dynamically based on user input? That is the process I am trying to learn. If html of the [link page] is simple enough, I imagine an easier method would be to make a popout div with that html. But what if it is a whole page that I need to dynamically generate?

Comment: You would need a way to distinguish page links from other links using classes and use class to assign event handlers

Comment: @charlietfl hmmm, could event handlers generate html dynamically? The idea is to avoid having to make a new page for every link and just have code on 1 page that alters depending on what link was clicked.

Comment: Yes absolutely. For example one class might be used for content section loading